# I tried to run my program in java and found this error

Tags: java

What does this warning mean? I had compiled my java program and found this warning in UI and does it have to deal with JVM.

> Some code changes cannot be hot swapped into a running virtual
>   machine, such as changing method names or introducing errors into
>   running code.
>
> The current target virtual machine from launch was unable to replace
>   the running code with the code in the workspace. It is safe to
>   continue running the application, but you may notice discrepancies
>   when debugging this application.
>
> Reason:
>   Hot code replace failed - Scheme change not implemented.

Comment: Please format your question to indicate which bit is the actual error, e.g. using a block quote (`>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you need to restart your application; the hot code replace (your change to the code) failed. Some changes aren't possible to running code using the [Java Platform Debugger Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html) (your message indicated two possible such changes, *changing method names* or *introducing errors into running code*).